# Panic button that redirects to a new page and deletes the website from history

Tags: html, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm working on a Mobile web application for abuse victims. I'm using Mean stack tools. I am completely new to mobile web development. I'm currently trying to create a panic button, so when someone enters the room, the user can click on the button which will navigate them to a new tab, while the website page is redirected to a less suspicious link, and the back button does not retrieve the website.

I found a website that successfully implements it:  pcadv.org

At this point, I've managed to create a button that opens a new tab, but everything I've tried from online sources won't cancel the original pages link.

How can I get my panic button to delete the history, or just not allow the user to go back?

I've attached my current code:

```html
 <a id =escape target="Escape" target="_blank"                 href="http://google.com">
        <h4> Escape</h4>
        </a>
```

Thanks